# How can I check in Visual Basic if string has duplicate symbols

Tags: vba, visual-studio, function

I'm making Bulls And Cows game and I want to randomly generate a number with four different digits.

```
Randomize()
Do
    Random = Int(9000 * Rnd()) + 1000
    'If (hasDupes = True)
    randomTwo = Random
    For i = 0 To randomTwo.Length - 1
        For j = 0 To randomTwo.Length - 1
            If randomTwo(i) = randomTwo(j) Then
                dupes = False
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    Next
Loop Until dupes = True
```

^ That's what I have so far but it ain't working. Is there any function how I can find if there are duplicate characters or where is my mistake ?

Comment: You could build from 4 random 0 to 9's and use the exists function of a dictionary to check for dupes.

Comment: Yeah, Like Nathan said, just generate 4 random single digit numbers then combine them into one final integer after checking for dupes.

Comment: If you don't want to use dictionary, append your numbers to a string and check for duplicates.

Comment: Please clarify.  You indicate you want to generate a "number" (so we can't have leading zeros), with four different digits (so no digit may be equal to another).  Correct?  That makes the range 1023 - 9876?

Comment: Did either of the answers below work for you? If so please mark one as correct. It is something only the person posing the question can do. Click on the green check mark by the one that is correct, the one you used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here my implementation

```
Dim sResult As String  
Dim iCnt As Integer  
Dim iTmp As Integer  

iCnt = 0
Do While iCnt < 4
    iTmp = Int(10 * Rnd())
    If InStr(sResult, CStr(iTmp)) = 0 and not (iCnt = 0 and iTmp = 0) Then
        sResult = sResult & CStr(iTmp)
        iCnt = iCnt + 1
    End If
Loop

Debug.Print sResult
```

EDIT: Additional check first number must be > 0 after reading RLH comment

Answer (score 0):

This will return four unique numbers.

```
Sub unique4()
Dim n(1 To 4) As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim t As Integer
Dim hr as Boolean

n(1) = 9 * Rnd()
i = 2
Do
    hr = False
    n(i) = 9 * Rnd()
    For t = 1 To i - 1
        If n(t) = n(i) Then
            hr = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next t
    If Not hr Then
        i = i + 1
    End If
Loop While i < 5

Debug.Print n(1) & n(2) & n(3) & n(4)

End Sub
```